# Generate Artificial Window Resize TKinter Python

Tags: python, image, tkinter, window, python-imaging-library

I have a tkinter program that has the following function copied from a youtube tutorial to dynamically resize the canvas as the window size changes.

```
def resize_image(event):
    global image, resized_image, new_image
    image = Image.open('1613768_night-sky-png-meteor-stars-night-sky-meteorday.png')
    resized_image = image.resize((event.width, event.height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    new_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=new_image, anchor='nw')
```

I have the canvas bounds starting with it taking up the full screen, because if I don't then the image will never be able to cover the entire screen. However, I want the window to open at a size smaller than full screen. As such, the full image isn't visible because it extends past the window bounds, and it only fits the window once I resize it, so at the start you can really only see the top left quadrant of the image. Is there a way to trigger resize_image by passing a false event into it that resizes the window by, say, 1x1?

If this is helpful, I am using .place() to put my canvas on the screen. I am using grid but I can't add the image to the grid because then it doesn't work as a background image, and I can't use the expand option of .pack() because I am using grid already.

Also, an artificial mouse click anywhere in the window doesn't work, it must be an artificial resize attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for this random import

```
from tkinter import *                                                                       # IMPORTS //////////////////
import random

root = Tk()                                                                                 # WINDOW ATTRIBUTES ////////
size_x = random.randint(0, 999)    # x coord
size_y = random.randint(0, 999)    # y coord
root.geometry("%dx%d" % (size_x, size_y))   # format to decimal

mainloop()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem as this just sets the window to an initial size. I need a way to trigger a window resize as soon as the tkinter window opens.